# Unable to run compiled Matlab code that uses "Presentation" for report generation

Tags: matlab, report, powerpoint, exe, matlab-compiler

I am trying to convert a simple program that uses "Presentation" (from reportgen package) to a .exe.

The code is as follows:

```
makePPTCompilable();
import mlreportgen.ppt.*
slides = Presentation('mySlideAddPresentation.pptx');
slide1 = add(slides,'Title and Picture');
plane = Picture(which('tulips.jpg'));
plane.X = '4in';
plane.Y = '4in';
plane.Width = '5in';
plane.Height = '2in';
add(slide1,plane);
close(slides);
```

I get the following error on running the complied version:

" Undefined function 'Presentation' for input arguments of type 'char'"

Any idea what I am missing here?I am on 2015b, used the following link for help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/rptgen/ug/compile-a-presentation-program.html

Comment: The link you give is for the R2016b documentation.  Have you checked the R2015b documentation to see if that functionality existed in that release?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the reportgen compilable, see [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/251898-matlab-report-generator-append-function-error) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/rptgen/ug/compile-a-report-program.html)

In my code I put:

```
  if ismcc || isdeployed
    % Make sure DOM is compilable
    makeDOMCompilable()
  end
```

Then it compiles fine! :)